# Is it possible to use HTML5's pushState() across multiple domains?

Tags: html, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy, history.js

I have almost impossible problem, but I am hoping someone could come up with some working solution or workaround.

I have a website where I use [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js) to do on-demand page changes to prevent loading full page when clicking on links. My website however has multiple domains, so cross-domain policy doesn't allow change full URL with host, only relative path can be changed/set.

Can anyone help me, how to make use of History.js and overcome cross-domain policy ? However, I can't stop using those multiple domains, so single domain is not solution.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I wish there was a way to make this happen. Some way the domains would allow each other to do this. Didn't find anything either tho..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not possible for a security reason. Allowing cross-domain pushState would allow malicious domains to masquerade as a trusted one.