# How to change the full URL of the page but not redirect in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting

I am trying to replace the full URL of the page with some other URL, and also don't want to redirect the page. I have tried the following methods but nothing helped.

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, 'www.google.com');
```

It just add the content as Hash, but didn't replace the full URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use HTML5's pushState() across multiple domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507641/is-it-possible-to-use-html5s-pushstate-across-multiple-domains)

Comment: If you want to make the user believe he's browsing Google while he's actually on your site, that's something that browser vendors actively try to prevent.