# JavaScript change address bar with new URL without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help.
I want to change address bar content, but i need replace whole addres including www.site.com/(domain)

I make a try with:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "new-url");
```

But without sucess. Please help?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should use replaceState

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8507641/1967864

Comment: You cannot use History API to change the URL to the URL of another domain.

Comment: Use angular router feature

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use HTML5's pushState() across multiple domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507641/is-it-possible-to-use-html5s-pushstate-across-multiple-domains)

Comment: @HarshKanakhara Where do you see OP using angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) api only allows you to modify the url within the same [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin), which is `<scheme> "://" <hostname> [ ":" <port> ]`. The `pushState` api will allow you to modify the path, query parameters, and url fragment. The reason you can't modify the origin is because of the [Same-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), which provides a guarantee that one origin cannot interfere with another origin. The policy exists to provide security guarantees on the web, such as confining malicious JavaScript to a single origin so it can't affect other websites.

Comment: this is not solution for my problem, i still can't change address content? You mean its is impossible?

Comment: Without doing a redirect you can only change the path, query parameters, and fragment. You cannot change the origin without doing a redirect.